Besides Nagakado, what is the situation of Toranaga's children in "Shōgun"?
In the 2024 miniseries Shōgun, we've only seen two of Lord Yoshii Toranaga's children on screen so far—his son Nagakado, who played a major role, and a newborn baby from Toranaga's consort, Lady Shizu. However, the show reveals that the powerful daimyo has other offspring as well.
For one, Toranaga's daughter-in-law, Lady Ochiba's sister (I'm not sure if she's the character named Rin—but she's not Nagakado's wife), was pregnant and later gave birth to Toranaga's granddaughter. Then, in Episode 9, Lord Ishido mentions that Toranaga has other sons (plural) besides Nagakado.
As far as I can recall, the show hasn't really explained where Toranaga's daughter-in-law's husband and these other sons of his are or what happened to them. Did I miss any details about their situations?
Understanding Toranaga's familial situation would provide valuable context for his political power and standing. With

 Nagakado gone

and war brewing, knowing if Toranaga had other potential heirs or allies within his own family could shed light on his options at that turbulent time.
If the show doesn't clarify this, I'd appreciate any insights from the original Shōgun novel by James Clavell that the miniseries is based on. 

In episode 8 we meet Lady Rin, who recently gave birth to Toranaga's granddaughter. It is also briefly mentioned that Rin has a sister, but it is unclear if she is Toranaga's daughter or daughter-in-law, from the context, it seems like the former.
In episode 9, when Mariko says that "Toranaga still mourns his son", she is met with the reply "He has others". Later Mariko mentions that "her lord hasn't seen his youngest son yet".
This means that Toranaga has other children and at least one grandchild.

I believe Rin (Ochiba's sister) is Toranaga's daughter-in-law. I'm wondering where her husband (Toranaga's son) is and what happened to him.

@galacticninja I am unsure: if Rin is daughter-in-law, then this means that Nagakado had an elder brother, who would be potentially eager for revenge and Rin says that "her family will be spared".- not a smart move. Also, the place of such (presumably) oldest son would be close to his father as the potential heir, instead, we see only Nagakado who is barely a teenager. But anyway it says that Rin is related to Toranaga either by blood or by marriage.
